# How can I get a derived iterator from a vector of unique_ptr<Base>?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator, unique-ptr

I have a base class (`Container`) that hold every kind of object (`Base` items) in a vector of `std::unique_ptr<Base>` and I have a derived class (`FolderOfFolders`) that only hold specific items (`Folder` items). I want to use the range-based-for to traverse that specific object (the `FolderOfFolder`) but I don't know how can I do that. With range-based-for I can get back `std::unique_ptr<Base>` items but I want `const Folder*` ones. I know that I need a begin(), end() pair to provide iterators for range-based-for but I need a cast from `std::unique_ptr<Base>` to `const Folder*`. Is this possible somehow?

```
class Container : public Base {
  public:
    // I want to get back these as Folder* from FolderOfFolders
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> items;
};

class Folder : public Container {
  public:
   // I want to call this when I traverse FolderOfFolders with range-based-for
   void folderMethod();
   ...
};

class SystemFolder : public Folder {
  public:
   ...
};

class UserFolder : public Folder {
  public:
   ...
};

class FolderOfFolders : public Folder {
  public:

    // I know that every item is a Folder in items
    // can I get an iterator to a Folder* ?!
    iterator begin() {
      //  ???
      return items.begin();
    }
    iterator end() {
       // ???
       return items.end();
    }
};
```

I want to use it as

```
FolderOfFolders folderOfFolders;
for (folder : folderOfFolders)
  folder->folderMethod();
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want to make sure the pointer is of type `Folder*` or just get a `const Folder*` from the iterator?

Comment: Looks to me like you'd need to create your own custom iterator, which wraps the vector iterator, with a different return type.

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you declared `Folder::folderMethod()` and `items`. And `Base`.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Container::items is in the example but I will ad an void folderMethod() to the Folder class.

Comment: Oh sorry, yes, `Folder` is a `Container`, that's where `items` comes from

Comment: @Industrial-antidepressant BTW the fact that you need to do this points to Bad Design, X vs Y problem. Holding a collection of Base objects is, as you've seen, useless unless you know the type, so just know the freakin type. IMHO you should have `template <class T> Container : public Container<Base>` with using type traits is_base_of. Container<Base> should be a specialization that exposes a base iterator. Everyone wins.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: Every type has an enum.

Comment: @Industrial-antidepressant That just means your not using polymorphism, AND trying to reproduce RTTI in your code. My change only effects that insofar as it makes your code much more flexible. Allow your "enum" type to have a "contiainer" bit (instead of its own enum) and you'll get be alot more flexible. But it is absolutely the wrong design, IMHO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>

struct Downcast
{
  typedef const Folder* result_type;

  result_type operator()(const std::unique_ptr<Base>& p) const
  { return static_cast<const Folder*>(p.get()); }
};

class FolderOfFolders : public Folder {
  public:

    typedef boost::transform_iterator<Downcast, decltype(items)::iterator> iterator;

    iterator begin() {
      return iterator(items.begin(), Downcast());
    }
    iterator end() {
      return iterator(items.end(), Downcast());
    }
};
```

N.B. because `FolderOfFolders::iterator::operator*` returns a `const Folder*` by value, that means `FolderOfFolders::iterator::reference` is not a reference type, and so the iterator is only an InputIterator, not a RandomAccessIterator like the underlying `vector::iterator`, but that's good enough to use with range-based `for`.

However, this "everything is a `Base`, and all collections are collections of `Base`" smells like Java. There are better designs. Even if you have to store containers of `Base`, you could do this instead of having to alter the iterator type:

```
const Folder& asFolder(const Base& b) {
  return dynamic_cast<const Folder&>(b); 
}

class FolderOfFolders : public Folder {
  public:

    typedef decltype(items)::iterator iterator;

    iterator begin() {
      return items.begin();
    }
    iterator end() {
      return items.end();
    }
};

...

for (auto& base_ptr : folderOfFolders)
  asFolder(*base_ptr).folderMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is references:

```
for (auto &folder : folderOfFolders)
    folder->folderMehod();
```

`std::unique_ptr<>` objects are not copyables, but you can bind the iteration with a reference.

Comment: That avoids trying to copy `folder` but it doesn't help call `Folder::folderMethod()` because `folder` is `std::unique_ptr<Base>`

Comment: Sorry, my fault, the folderMethod(); is in the Folder class not in the Base